# Import MySQL-Entrys in Elasticsearch over Logstash

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, logstash

I wanted to know how I can easily import data from my `MySQL` Database to my `Elasticsearch` Server using `Logstash`.

I have a Spring Boot App and want to import the information there.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Let me point you in the right direction: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, just feeled overrushed by the documentation from elastic.co but after a few hours more researching it is more clear now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to import data from a `MySQL` data to your elasticsearch index, you should be using the `jdbc` plugin as @hurb suggested above.

Your logstash `jdbc` input could look like this:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://yourhost:3306/yourdb" 
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "root"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "/pathtojar/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        schedule => "* * * * *" <-- if you need the query to be running continuously at a time span 
        statement => "SELECT * FROM yourtable" <-- change the query to your need        
        jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
        jdbc_page_size => "50000"
    }
}
```

The above is just a sample, so that you could reproduce. Hope it helps!

Comment: Just installed the jdbc-plugin for your solution. When I execute my .conf file I get an error:

NameError: missing class name ('org.apache.logging.log4j.Level')

Comment: What's the ES version ?

Comment: 2.4.0 because I am working with Spring Boot and Spring Data Elasticsearch and they are using the ES 2.4.0 version

Comment: But I get this Error even if my .conf-File is empty

Comment: Which means it's not something wrong with the conf. Do you have the necessary dependencies for log4j?

Comment: At this moment I start the logstash.bat with my command line from windows and not over our spring boot app.

Comment: So there is no log4j-Dependency

Comment: **Resolution** - it was the version 5.1.1 from logstash! Downgraded to 2.4.0 and it worked